# Connection pool gets exhausted, Not able to receive free connection

Tags: spring, hibernate

After serving around some request on heavy load the server starts showing these error continuously...... strong text

This is a stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1144)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    ... 62 more
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:173)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1144)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    ... 63 more
```

These are the spring and hibernate dependency i am using

- spring 3.1.0
- commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
- hibernate-3.6.1.Final
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.2.jar

I am using these configuration for handling the request... in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="springDS"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://xxxxx/xxxxxx
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>xxxxxx</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>xxxxx</value>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="dbcpDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxxx/xxxx"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxxxxx" />
    <property name="password" value="xxxxx" /> 
    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="200" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="50" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="true">

            <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dbcpDS" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>

            <!-- prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop> <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop> <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</prop -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Anyone having any idea please give a response.

Comment: Resource leak in your code?

Comment: Ya may be a resource leak but where it is happening Actually the same code is working fine with spring 3.0.5 but after upgrading it to spring 3.1.0 it is showing these type of error

Comment: Sir if you know something please tell me any link to refer??

Answer (score 2):

Here is typical option you have to resolve connection leak / pool exhaustion:

- Increase maximum pool capacity
- Make you queries run faster so connection get returned to the pool sooner
- Check for code that doesn't close connection when exception is thrown

I would start with analysing queries running on mysql. If you have MySQL workbench you can use the Server Administration module to see what queries currently running, how long they run for etc.

If your program indeed issuing long running queriesbyou need to fix this. Other possibility is your code throwing exceptions (most likely unchecked) but not closing the connection afterwards

I'm sure there's also a tool that can analyze what's your most long-running SQL, server throughput etc

Since you mention Spring 3.1.x, also check [the list of JIRA ticket fixed between 3.0.5 to 3.1.0](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3aversions-panel) and see if any might affect your program

Comment: Sir, Is there any method through which i can debug that where my connection is not getting back to pool or basically for checking where is the connection leak

Comment: Strictly, the two first bullets won't resolve a resource leak, only mitigate the effects of one. Agree with the rest of the post, perhaps throw in some JMX instrumentation.

Comment: @Ashish you can set org.hibernate.transaction (or org.hibernate.engine.transaction for Hibernate 4.2.2 > ) logger to DEBUG to see transaction start / end. If you do programmatic transaction you can also do visual inspection to ensure every transaction is enclosed with try / catch block and session is closed on finally block (this is why declarative transaction is a winner)